# Is it possible to get back the list in stratifiedKFold?

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, k-fold

I'd like to do something like this :

```
Skf = sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True) 
ALPHA,BETA  = Skf.split(data_X, data_Y)
```

and then :

```
for train_index, test_index in ALPHA,BETA
```

However, it isn't working, why and how to bypass that problem ?

My idea is that I want to use the same split a few times at different part of my code... I don't know how to "stock" the split.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can specify the seed used by the random number generator, so that you obtain the same split over different runs. Just specify the `random_state` parameter!

```
SEED = 42
Skf = sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,
                                              shuffle=True,
                                              random_state=SEED)
```

Comment: what is SEED, it is something I saw and couldn't understand. Is it fixing things?